# How do I format a string representation of an object exactly like print?

Tags: r, string-formatting

I'd like to format a named num vector as a string to add as a text label on a plot. I'd like the format of the string to be the same as or similar to `print`. Is there a function like `print` that rather than printing to the console returns a string? Here's a working code snippet. I'd like to replace `toString` with a function that includes the names of the vector elements.

```
library(lattice)
lm <- lm(hp ~ disp, mtcars)
xyplot(hp ~ disp, mtcars, type = c('p', 'r'),
    panel = function(...) {
        panel.xyplot(...)
        panel.text(median(mtcars$disp), lm$coefficients[1], toString(lm$coefficients))
    })
```

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot text in the plot area, you need to use user coordinates and the first two argument need to be x and y positions for the text vector that follows:

```
panel.text(x=c( 100,100, 150,150) ,y=c(300, 290, 300, 290), 
           c(  names(lm$coefficients), round(lm$coefficients, 2) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `names()` (take a look at `?names`).

It returns the value labels of the object.